# how can I get a custom timezone datetime from utc timestamp with javascript(node.js)

Tags: datetime, timezone, timestamp, momentjs

my backend server stores a utc timestamp with python and send it to frontend.

```
from datetime import datetime
utcTs = datetime.utcnow().timestamp()
```

and then frontend app (node.js) get the utcTs , convert it to locale time (or custom timezone)

I code like this:

```
moment.unix(utcTs).add(8,'hour').format()
```

because the utcTs is a utc+0 timestamp, how can I initialize a moment object as utc+0, so I can convert it to other timezone easily.

for example, my locale is utc+8.

```
moment.tz(utcTs,'Asia/Shanghai').format()
```

return a incorrect time.

is there any gentle way? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestamp returned from Python's `timestamp()` method is in terms of UTC-based seconds from the Unix epoch, so you just need to do the same thing in Moment.

```
// this is in seconds, but creates a moment in local mode
moment.unix(utcTs).add(8,'hour').format()

// you need to get it in UTC mode with the .utc().  Adding gives a moment 8 hours later.
moment.unix(utcTs).utc().add(8,'hour').format()

// this is how you get it in a fixed offset instead of adding
moment.unix(utcTs).utcOffset('+08:00').format()
```

Since not all time zones can use fixed offsets, the following is a better approach.

```
// this is incorrect, as the input would interpreted as milliseconds
moment.tz(utcTs,'Asia/Shanghai').format()

// this is the correct way for it interpreted in terms of seconds
moment.unix(utcTs).tz('Asia/Shanghai').format()
```

Comment: thanks Matt, this question puzzle me hours last night. The third method I have already tried. And  resultOf(line1) != resultOf(line3). Could you try it please? the line3's result has +08:00 timezone and is 8 hours before line1's result. My locale tz is +08:00.

Comment: console.log(moment.unix(utcTs).add(8,'hour').format())

console.log(moment.unix(utcTs).tz('Asia/Shanghai').format())

and the console print as below:

2018-01-05T12:39:52+08:00

2018-01-05T04:39:52+08:00

Comment: Adding 8 hours is not the same as adjusting to a time zone that is UTC+8.  Adding 8 hours is literally picking a different point in time that is 8 hours later.   (also, I'm pretty sure that first one would come out +00:00, not +08:00)

Comment: Ahh, I see my error - `moment.unix(...)` returns a moment in *local* mode.  I forgot that.  Sorry.   Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: because moment is calculate with the local timezone，so the result of first line is +08:00. my local timezone is +08:00.

Comment: Right, that make sense.  Still, don't conflate adding with changing the time zone or applying a fixed offset.  Adding changes the moment in time.  Adding is for something like when you have a start time and a duration and you want to know the end time.  It isn't for applying time zones.

Comment: I get what you said. But the utcTs is utc +8, how can I convert it to time/moment with timezone utc 0？ moment.unix(utcTs) is not correct because moment calculate as my local timezone utc +8

Comment: It will be correct if you immediately call `.utc()` as I showed.

Comment: should use datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp() instead of datetime.utcnow().timestamp() .